# css3 text shadow for text color #037ECC

Tags: css

I would like to give text shadow for my text using css3. Can anyone help me to apply text shadow. I tried using some online text shadow generators. But i couldn't able to get proper text shadow.

My site background color : white
My text color :  #037ECC

What shadow color i should use to get proper text shadow?

Thanks

Comment: text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000; 

                _____ PS:black is always good

Comment: @AlexC It completely changed my text color. Look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zdd4w/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this really isn't complicated.

`text-shadow: 1)px 2)px 3)px 4);`

1) horizontal length
2) vertical length
3) blur radius
4) color hex/rgb/rgba

try this: http://css3generator.com/ or http://www.midwinter-dg.com/blog_demos/css-text-shadows/

what exactly do you have in mind?

Comment: Hey just check my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Viruthagiri/Zdd4w/2/). It doesn't look nice. I want text shadow but it should not change my text color. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @user1091558 well, this really depends on the browser you are displaying your site in and on the font you are using. Chrome has quite some problems with this. Firefox and Opera display it quite nicely. Shadows should not differ to much from your text color. #037ECC and black for example are a bad idea.